# Loading .sh file in Gitlab CI pipeline step as script

Tags: linux, shell, virtual-machine, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I would like to copy my long pipeline step for testing which is 40 lines big to a external .sh file. But when I load the .sh file every step is processed, but it seems not inside my docker executor or whith wrong access rights. Every line of the .sh file directly inside the script part of the job does exactly what it should do.

Here is the snippet:

```
test:
    image: node:6
    services:
        - name: mysql:5.7
    stage: test
    script:
        - sh test.sh
    tags:
        - docker
    when: manual
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is in the log ?

Comment: did you solve the issue? I had the same idea to run a shell script or source a file at least.